# Inputs in HTML Form in Firefox do not respond

Tags: firefox, forms

I have an HTML form in my site, and for whatever reason I am unable to enter text in the inputs when viewing the site in Firefox (and only Firefox). My form is set up as follows:

```
             <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<form action="/MyAction/" method = "post" id="register">

                    <div class="registerField">
                        <label for="signupFirstName" class="registerLabel">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="signupFirstName" id="signupFirstName" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="registerField">
                        <label for="signupLastName" class="registerLabel">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="signupLastName" id="signupLastName" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="registerField">
                        <label for="signupPassword" class="registerLabel">Enter Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="signupPassword" id="signupPassword" autocomplete="off" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="registerField">
                         <label for="retypeSignupPassword" class="registerLabel">Re-enter Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="retypeSignupPassword" id="retypeSignupPassword" autocomplete="off" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div id="registerButtons">
                            <label for="signupButton">
                                <input type="submit" value = "Create Account" name = "registerButton" id="signupButton"/>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I had a callback attached to the keyup event on the form (which did indeed register the event), but that has since been disabled and I still have this problem. Also, when I right-click and select "Inspect Element" on any of the input elements to launch Firebug, everything works. Thanks in advance for any and all advice.

**EDIT:** Thanks to everyone who's commented so far. Below is the Javascript method off of the controller we use to coordinate the form:

```
        if (this.view.hasClass("readyToSubmit"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        var email = viewState.userState.user.EmailAddress;
        var password = $("#signupPassword").val();
        var passwordConfirm = $("#retypeSignupPassword").val();
        var firstName = $("#signupFirstName").val();
        var lastName = $("#signupLastName").val();
        var isOrg = false;

        if (!isValidEmail(email))
        {
            this.registerStatusController.set("Invalid email");
            return false;
        }

        if ((password == null) || (password == undefined) || (password.length < 6))
        {
            this.registerStatusController.set("Please enter a total of at least 6 letters, numbers, and symbols for your password");
            return false;
        }

        if (!(password == passwordConfirm))
        {
            this.registerStatusController.set("Your passwords do not match");
            return false;
        }

        if (firstName == '' || lastName == '')
        {
            this.registerStatusController.set("You must provide a first and last name.");
            return false;
        }

        requestController.post("/Home/MyAction",
            {
                username: email,
                password: password,
                passwordConfirm: passwordConfirm,
                firstName: firstName,
                lastName: lastName,
                timeOffset: -(new timezoneJS.Date()).getTimezoneOffset(), //Our tzo is negative of server side tzo
                isOrganization: isOrg
            },
            $.scope(this.callbackRegistered, this),

            function (XMLHttpRequest, textstatus, errorThrown)
            {
                this.registerStatusController.set("A system error has occurred.  Please try again later.");
            });


        return false;
    }

    this.callbackRegistered = function (data, textStatus)
{
    if (data == 0)
    {
        viewState.userState.isProvisional = false;
        this.registerStatusController.set("New account created");
        this.view.addClass("readyToSubmit");
        // $("#register").submit();

        // Run the post-registration action and then clear it.
        if (this.postRegisterAction)
        {
            this.postRegisterAction();
            this.postRegisterAction = null;
        }
        this.hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $('body').css("cursor", "auto");

        if (data == 1)
        {
            this.registerStatusController.set("You are already logged in");
        }
        else if (data == 3)
        {
            this.registerStatusController.set("Your account is already registered");
        }
        else if (data == 4)
        {
            this.registerStatusController.set("Your invitation code is not valid");
        }
        else
        {
            this.registerStatusController.set("The system is not available at this time.  Please try again later.");
        }
    }
}
```

No CSS has been defined on these inputs.

One other thing: this form is stored in a pop-over div that overlays the entire page. Its CSS is defined below:

```
#registerPopOver
{
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The form resides in a div within #registerPopOver:

```
#registerPopOverInner
{
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 20%;
    border: 1px #CCC solid;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

Thank you all again for your advice.

Comment: There's no reason I can from your snippet why the form inputs shouldn't work. What version of Firefox? Have you tried disabling Firebug?

Comment: Works just fine in Firefox 7 (and I really don't know why it shouldn't). Could we see the rest of the code?

Comment: are you applying and css to the inputs?

Comment: @Dennis Thanks for your response. I've posted some additional relevant code, I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm still not seeing any reason why it shouldn't work. Any chance you could post a link to a "working" example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the problem. Turns out a javascript-based calendar was stealing our focus. Thanks to everyone who responded!